# May one use "on" at bottom surface?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-request, verbs

May I use "on" on bottom surface? Like, I want to stick a sticker at the bottom side of a mouse. May I use "I stick a sticker on a mouse"? Or do I have to use under?

Also, stick a sticker sounds weird and redundant. I bet there is a better verb for a sticker. What is it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "I want to put a sticker on the underside of a mouse."

You are right that "stick a sticker" sounds redundant, and if you say "put a sticker", it will be assumed that you will be using its adhesive to put it in place.

To say you are putting a sticker "under" a mouse would be ambiguous, because it could be on the table under the mouse.

If you use the word "underside" it will be clear that the sticker is attached to the bottom side of the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using *bottom*, but you can get rid of any ambiguity by replacing *on* with *to*—especially if you want to use a different verb:

- I want to **apply** a sticker *to* the bottom of a mouse.
- I want to **attach** a sticker *to* the bottom of a mouse.
- I want to **affix** a sticker *to* the bottom of a mouse.
- I want to **adhere** a sticker *to* the bottom of a mouse.